# Incorrect Position in IE Only

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I have a table that is displaye correctly in chrome anf firefox but not in IE.The problem is an image that I use as a separator between records, which position is not correct in IE

```
   <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" height="100%">

   <table width="100%"  height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

   <tr> 
   <td style="width:250px !important;" colspan="1"><img src="../../images/dot.gif" width="163" height="1"></td>
   <td  width="1" background="../../images/white-dot.gif"></td>
   <td><img src="../../images/dot.gif" width="163" height="1"></td>
   </tr>    

 <% while not kitemRecordset.EOF
  ItemId = itemRecordset.fields("WORKITEM_ID")
     itemView= ItemId &" "& itemRecordset.fields("ITEM_SHO")

   %>
  <tr> 
    <td style="width:250px !important; word-break: break-all;"><a        href="../item/_item.asp?item_id=<%=ItemId%>&hometoURL=<%=Server.URLEncode(navpath & "/de/ti/pl.asp")%>" > 
    <%=itemView%></a></td>


    //problem here


    <td  background="../../images/white-dot.gif"><img src="../../images/white-dot.gif" width="1" height="8"></td>
     <td style="width:250px !important; word-break: break-all;"><%=itemRecordset.fields("item_Release")%></td>
      </tr> 
     <%ticketWorkitemRecordset.MoveNext
    If not itemRecordset.EOF then
     %>
     <tr>
     <td align="center" class="subnav" colspan="3" height="1"><img src="../../images/white-dot.gif" width="100%" height="1"/></td>
     </tr>
   <%end if%>                                               
   <%   
    wend %>
    </table>

    </td>
```

Comment: You use a lot of deprecated HTML attributes. Learn proper HTML first.

Comment: @Raptor it's an old project that wa coded by other poeple, I interfer only to fix problems within it.

Comment: But layout rendering is directly affected by your validity of your HTML codes.

Comment: that's why I'm here. Code works fine in all browsers but not in IE

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? its impossible to work out your problem without seeing it in action

Comment: Are you using a css reset?

Comment: This is more about [tag:html] and [tag:css] then it is about [tag:asp-classic], just because your source has a bit of Classic ASP in it is entirely inconsequential to the actual problem. By creating a quick "static" HTML mockup of this structure you will find the issue a lot quicker, using something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will help (as @JamesKing suggested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved bu adding style="width:250px !important;" on the  of the head form